# Prove or disprove: The function is bounded: $f(n) = n + \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove or disprove: The function is bounded: $f(n) = n + \frac{1}{n}$
>   where $n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus 0$

I show that function has infimum and supremum and if it has both it's bounded.

supremum:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)= \infty$$

infimum:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow -\infty}\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)= -\infty$$

We found that the function has a supremum and an infimum but because both are infinite, function isn't bounded.

---

Did I do it correctly? I don't want know another way of doing it (except it doesn't work as I did here), I only want know if you can do it like that and if it's correct please!

Comment: Can you write down the definition of "bounded"?

Comment: Also...are you quite sure you want $n\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$?  Usually, when one speaks of sequences the terms are, well, sequential.  That is we take $n\in \mathbb N$  maybe $n \in \mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z-\{0\}$.

Comment: Oh it's because I made this task myself.. Sry then I say it's function..

Comment: Still, write down the definition of a bounded function.

Comment: Function is bounded when it's continuous on its entire domain and has limit for $+- \infty$?

Comment: That's nothing like the definition.  You don't need continuity nor is there any condition on any limit.  Try reading about [Bounded Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is entirely incorrect.

- You speak of a *sequence*, but then say that $n\in\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. If $a_n$ is a sequence, then $n\in\mathbb N$.
- $2$ is not a supremum, since the third element of the sequence is equal to $3+\frac13$...
- Your calculation of the supremum is not correct. Taking the limit as $n\to 1$ of a **sequence** (not a function) makes no sense.
- Your calculation of the infimum is not correct. An infimum of a sequence is not the same as the limit of that sequence. And also, the limit, if anything, would be $\infty$.
- You conclude that the sequence has an infimum (which it does), but you "showed" that the infimum is $-\infty$. You cannot conclude that it is bounded from that.

Comment: Ty! I editted it now. Is it right?

Comment: I can't conclude sequence is bounded if it has infimum and supremum?

Comment: @cnmesr Not if the supremum is infinite, no. Would you say that the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6,7\dots$ is bounded? Well, it has a supremum ($\infty$) and an infimum $(1)$, so by your logic it is bounded.

Comment: Ahh, so if there exists infimum and supremum and both of them aren't infinite, then I can say it's bounded?

Comment: @cnmesr Yes. Also, note that supremum is **not** the same as limit.

Comment: Damn this is all so unclear (I don't mean your answer, I mean the way it's done..), maybe you can show me a good site where it's explained if you got one in mind? And the same thing I can apply for sequence and function right? It's same method.

Comment: @cnmesr It's not the same method. The methods are *similar*, but conceptually quite different. And grasping these concepts is not something that can be done by reading a site. It takes weeks at best. I recommend an introductory book into calculus, and lots of patience.